# Browser-sync slow to reload

Tags: gruntjs, browser-sync

I'm using the browser-sync grunt plugin and it is working, however it is very slow compared to live-reload.

After saving a file it takes about 3 seconds before the browser starts to refresh the page. I'm not sure if this is an issue with browser-sync, my localhost, or is this the typical behavior of browser-sync?

Comment: BrowserSync is usually extremely fast - what's your localhost? something like Mamp?